# Need clarification about unsigned char * in C

Tags: c

Given the code:

```
...

int x = 123

...

unsigned char * xx = (char *) & x;

...
```

I have `xx[0] = 123`, `xx[1] = 0`, `xx[2] = 0`, etc.

Can someone explain what is happening here? I dont have a great understanding of pointers in general, so the simpler the better.

Thanks

Comment: An `int` is 4 bytes in 32-bit or 8 bytes in 64-bit. `123` fits in the least significant byte. Your `xx[0]` represents that byte, so has the value `123`. `xx[1]` is the next significant byte, which is `0`, and so on.

Comment: @lurker That makes a lot of sense, can you explain exactly why xx[i] does that?

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing the bytes (`char`s) of a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) `int` in sequence.  The number `123` in an `int` on a little-endian system will usually be stored as `{123,0,0,0}`.  If your number had been `783 (256 * 3 + 15)`, it would be stored as `{15,3,0,0}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain all the pieces in ASCII pictures.

```
int x = 123;
```

Here, `x` is the symbol representing a location of type `int`. Type `int` uses 4 bytes of memory on a 32-bit machine, or 8 bytes on a 64-bit machine. This can be compiler dependent as well. But for this discussion, let's assume 32-bits (4 bytes).

Memory on x86 is managed "little endian", meaning if a number requires multiple bytes (it's value is > 255 unsigned, or > 127 signed, single byte values), then the number is stored with the *least* significant byte in the lowest address. If your number were hexadecimal, `0x12345678`, then it would be stored as:

```
x: 78        <-- address that `x` represents
   56        <-- x addr + 1 byte
   34        <-- x addr + 2 bytes
   12        <-- x addr + 3 bytes
```

Your number, decimal `123`, is `7B` hex, or `0000007B` (all 4 bytes shown), so would look like:

```
x: 7B        <-- address that `x` represents
   00        <-- x addr + 1 byte
   00        <-- x addr + 2 bytes
   00        <-- x addr + 3 bytes
```

To make this clearer, let's make up a memory address for `x`, say, `0x00001000`. Then the byte locations would have the following values:

```
    Address   Value
 x: 00001000  7B
    00001001  00
    00001002  00
    00001003  00
```

Now you have:

```
unsigned char * xx = (char *) & x;
```

Which defines a pointer to an *unsigned char* (an 8-bit, or 1-byte unsigned value, ranging 0-255) whose value is the address of your integer `x`. In other words, the value contained at location `xx` is `0x00001000`.

```
xx:  00
     10
     00
     00
```

The ampersand (`&`) indicates you want the *address* of `x`. And, technically, the declaration isn't correct. It really should be cast properly as:

```
unsigned char * xx = (unsigned char *) & x;
```

So now you have a pointer, or address, stored in the variable `xx`. That address points to `x`:

```
    Address   Value
 x: 00001000  7B      <-- xx points HERE (xx has the value 0x00001000)
    00001001  00
    00001002  00
    00001003  00
```

The value of `xx[0]` is what `xx` points to *offset by `0` bytes*. It's offset by *bytes* because the type of `xx` is a pointer to an `unsigned char` which is one byte. Therefore, each offset count from `xx` is by the size of that type. The value of `xx[1]` is just one byte higher in memory, which is the value `00`. And so on. Pictorially:

```
    Address   Value
 x: 00001000  7B      <-- xx[0], or the value at `xx` + 0
    00001001  00      <-- xx[1], or the value at `xx` + 1
    00001002  00      <-- xx[2], or the value at `xx` + 2
    00001003  00      <-- xx[3], or the value at `xx` + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're doing something you shouldn't be doing...

That said... One part of the result is you're working on a little Endian processor.  The `int x = 123;` statement allocates 4 bytes on the stack and intializes it with the value 123;  Since it is little Endian, the memory looks like 123, 0, 0, 0 in memory.  If it was big Endian, it would be 0, 0, 0, 123.  Your char pointer is pointing to the first byte of memory where x is stored.

Comment: Casting and int to a char* is a common method of serialization. In fact it does not even break the strict-aliasing rule.

Comment: There is no guarantee that an int is 4 bytes.  I have seen 2, 4, and 8.  Plus, there are times when this is a perfectly acceptible technique, with the caveat that it is not for the inexperienced programmer, because things cn go horribly wrong very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char * xx = (char *) & x;
```

You take the address of x, you tell the compiler it is a pointer to a character[string], you assign that to xx, which is a pointer to a character[string]. The cast to (char *) just keeps the compiler happy.

Now if you print xx, or inspect it, it can depend on the machine what you see - the so-called little-endian ot big-endian way of storing integers. X86 is little endian and stores the bytes of the integer in reverse. So storing 0x00000123 will store 0x23 0x01 0x00 0x00, which is what you see when inspecting the location xx points to as characters.